# Fiddler can't track the traffic but httpAnalyzer can (connection looks like websockets)

Tags: fiddler

I need to explore the traffic from one program.

The program makes something like a connection through the WebSockets.

Fiddler displays this:

[image]
[image]

Request Headers: `CONNECT 144.***:443 HTTP/1.0`

Response: `HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established`

End empty body.

But the HTTP analyzer displays full information after that response, and that information continues flowing. Very likely like WebSockets (one connection and receive more answers).
[image]

And fiddler display zero traffic.

How can I explore such traffic through the fiddler?

Answer (score 1):

A CONNECT call is always the first command a client sends if it uses a Proxy. Translated CONNECT just means: Please start a connection to the following server and that port. Through that connection the real HTP calls are then transmitted. Therefore CONNECT is not a real HTTP
request.

Fiddler does not show the content of CONNECT requests/responses to port 443 endpoints because those connections are HTTPS/TLS protected (hence the shown data would be useless). You need to enable HTTPS decryption and install the Fiddler root CA certificate into the client app/OS to see the decrypted content of those connections.

Comment: HTTPS decryption is active. The root of the problem is that the protocol looks similar to websockets but with some modifications. But the protocol is unknown to Fiddler. In that case Fiddler by default just sent that data without tracking :( Now I try to investigate how to setup Fiddler to save all the data even with unknown protocol (more details about that issue are here https://www.telerik.com/forums/fiddler-can-t-track-traffic-but-httpanalyzer-can-connection-looks-like-websockets )